# How to design TextField

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to design TextField have red star in hint Text? Thank you for your helping.
[image]

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha I used two text_field_custom file, but I can't validate TextField! You can have the way to fix this problem.

Comment: Edit your question, what problem are you getting on it